# What is the ontological status of the laws of logic?

Tags: logic, ontology, philosophy-of-logic

Are the laws of logic abstract objects that exist independently of physical things? Are they the same in all possible worlds? Are they man-made constructs, nothing more than ideas in our minds? Or something else?

Comment: Maybe useful: Penelope Rush (editor), [The Metaphysics of Logic (Cambridge, 2014)](https://books.google.it/books?id=GEilBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA13); see page 13 (*Logical realism*): "Logic might chart the rules of the world itself; the rules of rational human thought; or both.

Comment: If you mean the 'laws of thought' I would say they are the laws of existence, independent of physical objects and the same in all universes. Thus the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics. This would be the way minds work and I would conjecture that all minds work, and thus the way our psycho-physical world works. Not an answer but an opinion.   .